# Laravel bulk insert and with relational one-to-one certain times

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bulkinsert

I know that that I can do a bulk insert like:

```
$data = [
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
];
Model::insert($data);
```

But my problem is that I need to do a bulk insert that sometimes depending on a item value can have a one-to-one relation with another table, currently I loop through my array of items that needs to be inserted and do this:

```
    for(...) { 
    $catCheck = $itemCategory;
    $newItem->insertItem($request, $userId);
    $itemId = $newItem->i_id;
    if ($catCheck == 8) {
         $iteminfo = new info();
         $iteminfo->insertInfo($request, $itemId);
    }
}
```

When I loop through my array of items with the code above it creates multiple insert queries which I dont want since its bad for performance.

So is there any way I can do a bulk insert that has a relation in some cases?

Comment: You could create an array which holds the ID of the elements that is looping and the ItemId that is going to be added to the ID. At the end of the loop create an Update that updates the elements as a group

Comment: @connormcwood could you provide a small example, I dont follow sorry